# MultiIndex Group By with customize column conclusion in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: sql, pandas, group-by

I desire to achieve something we do in sql as follows:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, mean(Column3), sum(Column4)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Column1, Column2
```

```
Store_Code  Brand_Code  Sales_Price

    1   18  28.00
    2   17  105.33
    2   17  65.33
    1   17  30.67
    1   18  6.67
```

As in above dataset I desire to group this dataframe with store code and taking most frequent brand code and sales price as it is or implementing some other operation like mean on sales price.

Currently all I am able to do is apply one single operation to all columns.

**something like this**

```
data.groupby(level=['Store_Code]).sum()
```

```
Store_Code  Brand_Code  Sales_Price

    1   18  17.33
        17  30.67

    2   17  85.33
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT Store_Code, Brand_Code , avg(Sales_Price)
FROM SomeTable 
GROUP BY Store_Code, Brand_Code
```